# Here Rest Category transport and airport

Tags: here-api

I'm working with restful place api and I curious why transport and airport are not the same category?
and transport category can show all land transport and sea but not airport...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

airport is a sub-category of transport. Querying for transport will return airports as well, e.g., http://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/explore?at=52.559%2C13.2977&cat=transport&app_id=demo_qCG24t50dHOwrLQ&app_code=NYKC67ShPhQwqaydGIW4yg has an airport as the first result.

You can query for the categories valid at a given point. This will return categories including child-parent relationship. Example: http://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places?app_id=demo_qCG24t50dHOwrLQ&app_code=NYKC67ShPhQwqaydGIW4yg&at=52.521%2C13.3807

Comment: oh... my bad, it's looks like my query I test didn't have airport nearby.... thank you